# iOS searching for a string inside of a string, or how to work with Yahoo weather

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to make a weather app. So far I managed to get some basic information from the rss. I am using the following code:

```
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {      
[currentLink appendString:string];}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to look up for child informations.
For example the wind variable has 3 sub variables: chill, speed, direction
I get the following xml

```
<yweather:wind chill="50"   direction="0"   speed="0" />
```

I am wondering how do I request this variable. Or how can I look up if there is
yweather:wind inside the tag

Comment: It is xml attributes. Any XML parser should be able to handle them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I understand about your problem is "you are unable to handle the attribute of any element"
if you use TBXML parser it will help you to solve your problem.
following is the link and example of your problem.

To extract attribute:

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Extracting_attributes.html

To learn TBXML

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides.html